# junit testcase is pass , but still printing exception in console java

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4, junit5

```
@Test
public void testGetAspectByAspectName() {
    try {
    this.getUserTwin();
    assertEquals(userAlmService.getAspectByUserName("6cade-bced-4e69-8red-271c95d343baa", null).toString(),this.getAspect().toString());
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        assertEquals(NullPointerException.class, e.getClass());
    }
}
```

My intention this test case to check nullpointerexception. The Test case passed but I am getting NULL exception message in the console
how to restrict to do not print in console
I tried @Test(expected=NullPointerexception.class) still it is printing in console

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

I am using sprinrunner

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```

Comment: Have you written e.printStacktrace() in getUserTwin() method ?

Comment: Which part exactly throws the exception; getUserTwin() or getAspectByUserName()?

Comment: Why are there two asserEquals? One of them are never reached, isn't it? You have a lot of .Methode().Methode() maybe there are more NullPointer

Comment: @Sambit no, I didn't write. Actually that exception coming from userAlmService.getAspectByUserName("6cade-bced-4e69-8red-271c95d343baa", null)

Comment: @Aykhan getAspectByUserName() 
from service layer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();
@Test
public void fooBar() throws FooBarException {
    exception.expect(FooBarException.class);
    exception.expectMessage(containsString("bla bla bla"));
    //your code here
}
```